# Is there a way to grab a variable inside a function inside a class from an imported file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Total noob here. There are two python files in this example. The first is cloned from github, the second is my own. The first is called city_data.py. Mine is called analyze.py. Within the city_data.py code there is a class with a prompt with many defined functions within the class. In my analyze.py file I want to run a specific function within the class.  I got the function to run (table output) but when I try to recall variables from the file it just says "NameError: name 'pop_dens' is not defined".  Is there a way to recall the variable pop_dens from my file while running the function on the imported file?

city_data.py

```
class city_stats():
    prompt = '> '
        def table_output(self, arg):
            pop_dens = SingleTable(volume,'city')
            ...
            print(table)
            ...
```

analyze.py

```
from city_data import city_data

analyze = city_stats()

density_output = analyze.table_output("Chicago")
print(pop_dens)
```

run analyze.py

```
table outputs successfully
"NameError: name 'pop_dens' is not defined"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access variable from another class use form class_name.class_variable.
in your case

```py
...
print(analyze.pop_dens)
...
```

Comment: This won't work unless `pop_dens` is an instance attribute.

Comment: You are right. My bad :)

Comment: this doesn't work. I get the error city_stats has no attribute pop_dens

Comment: Sorry, I didn't cearfully read yours code. If you want this to work you need to modify class city_data.

Add pop_dens = 0 or pop_dens =none
in first line of class

Comment: I was hoping to do this without modifying city_data.py since it will be frequently updated from github but when I add pop_dens = 0 in the first line of class it just returns 0 when I call it from analyze.py, even though the table output right above it displays pop_dens with the correct value. Any thoughts?